# Google is indexing pages so slowly that it will take 25 years to index all 8 milliion

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-index

We have a website with about 8 million pages
https://www.tibrains.com/
We try to index it, but have not very good results
We had about 13-14 000 indexed pages for the last several months
Then Google indexed about 100 000 pages in 2 weeks
Then 2 weeks we stayed on the same level
Then Google indexed 25 000 pages
And then we again have no results for 2 weeks
I attached the screenshot
[image]

Also, the crawl rate is very low... Only several time the crawl rate was high enough
[image]
With such a speed it will take about 25 years to index all the pages of our site
Is there any way we can speed up this process?

Comment: New sites never get indexed quickly.  Google indexes big sites only once they get lots of inbound links that show they have content that people find compelling.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the cause of the problem is that the content represents a completely anonymous affiliate program. Actually, the content of your website corresponds to **[Content policies for Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/10622781#zippy=%2Cdeceptive-practices)** about:

> **Deceptive practices**
>
> We don’t allow content that impersonates any
> person or organization, misrepresentation or concealment of ownership
> or primary purpose, and engagement in inauthentic or coordinated
> behavior to deceive, defraud, or mislead. This includes, but isn’t
> limited to, the misrepresentation or concealment of country of origin
> or directing content at users in another country under false premises,
> and working together in ways that conceal or misrepresent information
> about relationships or editorial independence.